# In Clash of clans, Will buildings under construction / upgrade halt its progress if your village has been destroyed?

Tags: clash-of-clans

For example I'm upgrading my town hall and its 5hours before completion, before it was completed my village was raided and completely destroyed. Will my town hall ever complete its upgrade within 5 hours if I was not able to open the game and repair the damage from the raid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting raided has no effect on any of your timers - upgrade or otherwise.  The destruction is merely cosmetic, although it will prevent you from interacting with the building for a few seconds.